# How to evaluate $\int \frac {dx}{\cos x+C}$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I want to evaluate  -

> $$\int \frac {dx}{\cos x+C}$$

Where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.I tried substitution and parts but could not do it.

Note that for $C=1$ one can simply do this by using compound angle formulas.But what about other values of $C $?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** use the substitution $t=\tan{\frac{1}{2}x}$. Then $dx = 2dt/(1+t^2)$, 
$$ \cos{x} = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, $$
and the integral reduces to that of a fairly simple rational function.

Comment: This is known as [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

Comment: @projectilemotion Thanks a lot!!:-)

Comment: Although Euler was apparently first to use it in integrals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Euler_and_Weierstrass

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Make the substitution $ \theta = \frac{x}{2}$.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{C + \cos 2 \theta} &= \frac{1}{C -1 + 2\cos ^2 \theta} \\
 &= \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{(C-1)\sec^2 \theta + 2} \\
&= \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{C + 1 + (C-1)\tan^2 \theta}
\end{align}
Hence

\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{C + \cos x} \text{d}x &= \int \frac{2}{C + \cos 2 \theta} d \theta \\
&= \int \frac{ 2\sec^2 \theta}{ C + 1 + (C-1)\tan^2 \theta} d \theta 
\end{align}

Now make the second substitution $t = \tan \theta$ and continue as above.

Comment: Typo there... it should be theta instead of y

Comment: @tatan Thanks! Wrote one variable on my notebook and another when it came to my answer.